Invisible reCAPTCHA not detecting selenium script
The login page of my website has an invisible recaptcha protection. But is not detecting a simple selenium script such as this:
def login_attack(driver, email):
  tries = 1
  driver.get(f'https://my-website.com/login');
  for password in password_generator():
    print(f'[{tries=}] [start] ')
    sleep(1)
    email_el = driver.find_element(By.ID, "email")
    email_el.clear()
    email_el.send_keys(email)
    print(f'[{tries=}] [element email] [send_keys {email=}]')
    pass_el = driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")
    pass_el.clear()
    pass_el.send_keys(password)
    print(f'[{tries=}] [element password] [send_keys {password=}]')
    check_score(driver)
    send_el = driver.find_element(By.ID, "sendBtn")
    send_el.click()
    print(f'[{tries=}] [element sendBtn] [click true]')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CLASS_NAME, "alert"), 'Could not login'))
    print(f'[{tries=}] [WebDriverWait end] [alert {driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "alert").text[2:]}]')
    tries += 1

In the checking recaptcha api (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify) the score is 0.9. Why reCAPTCHA is not detecting my selenium script?
Info:
I am importing recaptcha like this:
    <script recaptcha-v3-script="" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" async="" charset="utf-8" src="https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/5VlvD-iBu8lCD1bRhHoe_TTl/recaptcha__en.js" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-YkwUl3amqxfkswAVOL2Wj+VPc/W8ya9QU2cLyX631bSEe0tQD9jUsUL8FizZyb0h"></script>


probably a question for Google, but it may detect it but not consider it a "malicious" bot until it does something annoying enough.  Placing the recaptcha in multiple places throughout your site will help it make more accurate decisions based on behavior.  How many tries do you get through?  Seems like bot or no bot it should detect the behavior as questionable after 20 or so?

Yes, the bot took 20 tries to login. The function password_generator will only return the correct password after 20 tries
